# Tail call optimization by the compiler/interpreter for factorial function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

Is it possible to perform tail call optimization by the compiler/interpreter for the factorial function given below?

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (x)
    (if (= x 0)
        1
        (* x (factorial (- x 1))))))
```

I would like to get a brief explanation for the same.

From the comment by @rsm below I understand program should be written something like this:

```
(define fact
  (lambda (x accumulator)
    (if (<= x 1)
    accumulator
    (fact (- x 1) (* x accumulator)))))

(define factorial
  (lambda (x)
    (fact x 1)))
```

Or something like this:

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (let fact ([i n] [a 1])
      (if (= i 1)
      a
      (fact (- i 1) (* a i))))))
```

Comment: briefly - no. recursive call to `factorial` is not in tail position (there is multiplication that must happen after call to `factorial` returns). some call it *augmented tail call*. you have to rewrite your code to let evaluator/compiler use TCO.

Comment: Thanks @rsm for the explanation.

Comment: about your edit - **yes**, this is how *tail call* should look like! you are on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

First, a terminological issue: you, as the programmer, cannot "do" tail call optimization. (This is one of the reasons why "tail call optimization" is a bad name for this property.) In this case, the "optimization" is done by the evaluator; specifically, a correct evaluator for Racket or Scheme or any properly tail-calling language makes a promise: it promises not to use unbounded memory on certain types of programs. Specifically, programs that make only "tail calls."

So, what you're really asking is how you can convert your program to one that makes only tail calls. The key here is to understand tail calls, and to convert your program to accumulator style. And, at this point, I'm going to defer to the excellent discussion that appears in [Alexis King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655059/turning-structural-recursion-into-accumulative-recursion-in-racket/28655995#28655995).

Comment: Actually I want to know whether the compiler can do tail call optimization for the given code. I will clarify my question. In that sense, I hope this is not really a duplicate question. cc. @Óscar-lópez

Comment: Yes, a properly tail-calling evaluator should use bounded space to evaluate the code you've written, because all of your calls are in tail position. (I'm making the standard simplification of assuming that numbers can all be stored in constant space.)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to calculate `x!`.

You defined factorial as a *lambda* with input `x` (here it is in a readable pseudocode, not a prefix syntax as in Scheme):

```c
factorial (x) = {  
  (x=0) -> 1 // end condition  
  (x<>0) -> x * fact(x-1) // 'fact' should be 'factorial' AFAIK   
}
```

or in other words:

```
factorial(x) * factorial(x-1) * factorial((x-1)-1) ...factorial(0) => x!
```

the following is already tail recursive ( a recursion were the last call is the recursion):

```c
factorial (x , sum(1)) = {  
  (x=0) -> sum // end condition  
  (x<>0) -> fact(x-1 ,  sum(x*sum)) // 'fact' should be 'factorial' AFAIK   
}
```

back to code, should be something like:

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (x , sum=1)
    (if (= x 0)
      sum
      (fact (- x 1) (* x sum)))))
```

Comment: There is so many things wrong with your answer I would like to downvote it more than once.